# Unable to store strings in 2-D array using pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have stored names in file 'name.txt' as following:

```
1    name1
2    name2
3    name3
and so on...
```

After reading from file, I want to store names in 2-D array using pointers and arrange them in dictionary order using bubble short and save in another file.
My program to store names in memory is following:

```
FILE *ptr = fopen("D:\\name.txt", "r");
if (ptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Couldn't open name file. Error code 909\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* The function 'last_index()' returns the last index i.e maximum index of name after reading the 'name.txt'*/
int max_index = last_index(); // last index from file
int index;
char temp_name[50]; // to store name temporiraly which has been read from file in each iteration
printf("Point 1 reached successfully.\n"); //test 1

/* 'max_index' is a variable which stores the last index of name after reading from file*/
char (*name_list_file)[30] = (char (*)[30])malloc(max_index * 30 * sizeof(char)); //case 1

int i = 0;
while (feof(ptr) == 0)
{
    fscanf(ptr, "%d", &index);  // for reading index
    fgetc(ptr);                 // for reading whitespace
    fgets(temp_name, 50, ptr); // for reading name
    // now remving newline character added by fgets()
    temp_name[strlen(temp_name) - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(name_list_file[i++], temp_name); // saving the name in memory
}
fclose(ptr); // closing the file
printf("point 2 reached successfully");//test 2
```

Whene I execute the program, **test 1** printed successfully but program auto terminates before printing **test 2**. While when I use debugging in vs code then program runs successfully and prints both **test 1** and **test 2** and shorted names saved in file without any issue (I have not added that part of program).
Now, I am unable to locate the error (failed to execute but no issue in debugging). It may be error in allocating memory (**case 1**) but I am not sure.

Comment: Drop `feof(ptr) == 0` and check the result of each file handling function call. In case either of them fails in the middle of the loop body, then I suppose it might hang.

Comment: @Lundin But how is it working during debugging?

Comment: Undefined behavior?

Comment: @Lundin sorry, I didn't get 'undefined behavior?'

Comment: @Lundin Please see, is there any issue in allocating memory to `name_list_file`.

Comment: When the EOF in the next cycle occurs after reading the last line, your loop will try to read more data without any error checking and will write it to an array index 1 greater than the last valid index. Apart from correct error / EOF handling you should also terminate the loop if the array index is too large.

Comment: @Bodo: `feof()` returns a non-zero value if EOF has been reached and it causes termination of loop.

Comment: @Suraj You are right that "`feof` returns a non-zero value if EOF *has been reached*". `feof` does **not** tell you that the file pointer is *just before the end* of the file. It can only be used to distinguish between EOF and something else *after* a read operation has *returned an error/EOF* indication. See also `ferror`. In your program it depends on the input file. If the last line of the input file is not terminated by a newline character, `fgets` will be terminated by EOF. With a newline at the end of the last line, the EOF condition will be found only after the next `fscanf`.

Comment: @Bodo I got your point. Thanks.